# api.addAsyncRequestTransform is not a function error

Tags: react-native, axios

```js
const api = apisauce.create({
    // base URL is read from the "constructor"
    baseURL,
    // here are some default headers
    headers: {
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    },
    // 10 second timeout...
    timeout: 10000
  })

api.addAsyncRequestTransform(request => async () => {
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + await AsyncStorage.getItem('@nytevibetoken');
  });
```

throwing api.addAsyncRequestTransform is not a function error. Why? I want to fethc token from AsyncStorage and add it o header. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you exporting the function? It's an easy step to miss, I do it all the time.

Comment: No no, I never forget it 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to add transformations to async requests was introduced in version 0.10.0 of apisauce.

I attempted to execute your snippet in 0.8.0 and received the same error. Once I upgraded to 0.10.0, the error went away.

Check your package.json dependencies and update apisauce if required.

Comment: And That was the issue! I checked change log and upgraded it to sove it finally.